# talking face for debian

Tags: linux, open-source, debian

I'd like to add a talking face to my video tutorial.

I've found xface but its install instructions are windows only (though it is wxWidgets based, maybe debian instructions can be written). I've found [talkbots](https://sourceforge.net/projects/talkbots/files/) but not sure where is its downloads section. I have found [botlibre](https://www.botlibre.com/), but not sure how to install it (without proproetary 'desktop' version) locally.

I'm using debian, anything libre that works on a Linux would be great to have. I am looking for free (libre) solutions only.

> Are you looking for a library to include with your application code? Or about a ready-to-use application that produces some "Max Headroom" face?

Ready to use application. It should have a 'transcript' though: what usually goes in subtitles (i.e. "speak slower", "speak faster and sad", "make a surprised face expression", "say hello world", "turn right" etc).

> What kind of workflow should be involved then (as you somehow want to use your own material, and not just download a ready-to-view video)?

Yes make my own material.